# ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new trustedCertificatePolicy();

Tags: c#

I have added all the references for this but while rebuilding my code it gives returns me

The type or namespace name 'trustedCertificatePolicy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Do I need to add any other dll?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `TrustAllCertificatePolicy` ??

Something similar to this [example](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/258.aspx).